# java - double cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java

I have searched about this error but those didn't solve my problem.

field is, JTextfield as:

```
private java.util.List<JTextField> field;
```

I have a function as:

```
public static bank addDebt( double payment ) {
    return new bank( 1, payment );
}
```

and I'm calling it like and this line gives me error:

```
bank.addDebt( Double.parseDouble( field.get(9).getText() ) );
```

but this gives me :

> double cannot be dereferenced

revelent part of code:

```
private class listener implements ActionListener{
        @Override public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
            JButton clicked = (JButton)e.getSource();
            if( clicked == button.get(0) ){
                try {
                    PreparedStatement st = connect.prepareStatement("select * from caridata where code=?");
                    st.setString(1, field.get(0).getText() );
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                    while( rs.next() ){
                        //debt = rs.getDouble( "debt" );
                        //owe = rs.getDouble( "owe" );
                        //bank = rs.getDouble( "bank" );
                        for( int i=0;i<field.size();i++ ){
                            if( i == 1 )
                                field.get(i).setText( rs.getString( i+1 ) );
                            else if( i == 9 || i == 10 || i == 11 )
                                field.get(i).setText( Double.toString( rs.getDouble( i+1 ) ) );
                            else
                                field.get(i).setText( rs.getString( i+1 ) );
                        }
                    }
                    //
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error Code = 0005");
                }
            }else if( clicked == button.get(1) ){
                final JFileChooser fileDialog = new JFileChooser();
                int returnVal = fileDialog.showOpenDialog( frame );
                if( returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ){
                    java.io.File file = fileDialog.getSelectedFile( );
                    field.get(14).setText( file.getPath() );
                }
            }else if( clicked == button.get(2) ){
                try {
                    PreparedStatement st = connect.prepareStatement("update caridata set code=?,enterdate=?,by=?,itgroup=?,fullname=?,email=?,gsm=?,web=?,fax=?,debt=?,owe=?,bank=?,info=?,explain=?,image=? where code=?");
                    for( int i=0;i<field.size();i++ ){
                        if( i == 1 )
                            st.setDate( i+1, java.sql.Date.valueOf( field.get(i).getText() ) );
                        else if( i == 9 || i == 10 || i == 11 )
                            st.setDouble( i+1, Double.parseDouble( field.get(i).getText() ) );
                        else
                            st.setString( i+1, field.get(i).getText() );
                    }
                    st.setString(16, field.get(0).getText());
                    st.executeUpdate();
                    //bank.rmvDebt( debt );
                    //bank.rmvPayment( owe );
                    //bank.rmvTotal( bank );
                    //bank.addDebt( Double.parseDouble( field.get(9).getText() ) );
                    //bank.addPayment( Double.parseDouble( field.get(10).getText() ) );
                    //bank.addTotal( Double.parseDouble( field.get(11).getText() ) );
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"It's done");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error Code = 0006");
                } finally {
                    bank.addDebt( field.get(9).getText() );
                    bank.addPayment( field.get(10).getText() );
                    bank.addTotal( field.get(11).getText() );
                }
            }else if( clicked == button.get(3) ){
                for( int i=0;i<field.size();i++ )
                    field.get(i).setText("");
            }
        }// action
    }// listener
}
```

whole of

```
/bank.rmvDebt( debt );
                    //bank.rmvPayment( owe );
                    //bank.rmvTotal( bank );
                    //bank.addDebt( Double.parseDouble( field.get(9).getText() ) );
                    //bank.addPayment( Double.parseDouble( field.get(10).getText() ) );
```

gives  double cannot be dereferenced.

I've been doing this in other files but this time somethings happening and I did not know what it is. What am I missing ?

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: What's the type of `field`?

Comment: edited again to your question.

Comment: It's still not clear which line is causing the problem - and it doesn't help that you're not following Java naming conventions. (The type name should be `Bank`, not `bank`; when you say `bank.addDebt`, that *looks* like it's calling an instance method. It's pretty odd for an `addDebt` method to return a `bank`, too...)

Comment: is it clear by now ? I added the relevent part of code.

Comment: As per your code "bank.addDebt( Double.parseDouble( field.get(9).getText() ) ); " and " bank.addDebt( field.get(9).getText() );" Can you tell what parameter talking in this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks suspicious :

```
//bank = rs.getDouble( "bank" );
```

If it wasn't commented at some point, it would imply you have a `double` variable named `bank`, which may hide your `bank` class. That would explain the error you got, since `double` cannot be dereferenced (i.e. `bank.something` is invalid).

Comment: I have variable named by bank.

Comment: @VivianMaya If you have a `bank` variable of double type, that explains your error. Please change your `bank` class to `Bank`, or rename the `bank` variable.